# ansible to answer the prompts with pre answers

Tags: ansible

I have to uninstall a software and while un-installing that, it prompts to seek an answer as `yes or no` .. given the sample below.

```
# /opt/altiris/notification/nsagent/bin/aex-uninstall
This will remove the Symantec Management Agent for UNIX, Linux and Mac software from your system.

Are you sure you want to continue [Yy/Nn]?
```

Now, as i have multiple Linux systems to do it hence i'm looking for ansible to do the Job for me , So, i have just tested the same with ansible `adhoc` way as follows an it works with `shell` module...

```
# ansible all -m shell -a 'echo "y" | /opt/altiris/notification/nsagent/bin/aex-uninstall'
dev-karn | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
This will remove the Symantec Management Agent for UNIX, Linux and Mac software from your system.

Are you sure you want to continue [Yy/Nn]?

Uninstalling dependant solutions...
Uninstalling dependant solutions finished.

Removing Symantec Management Agent for UNIX, Linux and Mac package from the system...
Removing wrapper scripts and links for applications...
Sending uninstall events to NS
Stopping Symantec Management Agent for UNIX, Linux and Mac: [  OK  ]
Remove non packaged files.
Symantec Management Agent for UNIX, Linux and Mac Configuration utility.
  Removing aex-* links in /usr/bin
  Removing RC init links and scripts
Cleaning up after final package removal.
Removal finished.
```

is there a bettwr way to do it... 
any ideas will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You should use Ansible [expect](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/expect_module.html) module.

Comment: thnx for your revert , that i saw ob ansible doc. but ended with the solution with `yes`  utility repeatedly outputs y which fullfils the requirement

Answer (score 0):

The `yes` utility of linux shell repeatedly outputs `y` which fulfills the neccessity of every pre-answers seeking prompt by a program and so as to my requirement as the program i'm running that needs only answer is `yes` to proceed, hence i used it as below with ansible `shell` module ...

```
$ ansible all -m shell -a '/bin/yes | /opt/altiris/notification/nsagent/bin/aex-uninstall'
```

So, even `echo "y"` is not neeed.

Thnx - Karn